# Invalid type error in c++ code in output[left]=input[i] line

Tags: c++, arrays

I am getting this

```
'invalid types int*[std::ios_based&(std::ios_base&)]' for array subscript  in line                   
output[left]=input[i];
```

Can't able to figure out the solution to it.  here output is the array in which i want my answer

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void recover(int input[], int output[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int mid = n / 2;
    if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
        output[mid] = input[i];
        int left = mid - 1;
        int right = mid + 1;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        int left = mid - 1;
        int right = mid;
    }
    while (i < n)
    {
        output[left] = input[i];
        left--;
        i++;
        output[right] = input[i];
        right++;
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input[100], output[100];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> input[i];
    }
    recover(input, output, n) for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << output[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `int left=mid-1;` goes out of scope before it is used here `output[left]=input[i];`, same for `right`.  Fix these and compile again. Typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a scope problem, as Richard Critten pointed out in comments. `right` and `left` do not have the definition in the `while` loop that you gave them in the `if` and `else` statements.

Compounding this, you use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`. These are not causing your issue, but they are making it harder to understand.

[Using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077). It includes the entirety of the C++ standard library, which is lazy, unnecessary, and increases compile times. It's also not portable.

[Using `using namespace std;` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). It makes everything in namespace `std` available without qualification. This means any common names like `left` and `right` may match [something you didn't intend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left). This can lead to bugs that are horrendously difficult to find and fix.

Using both together is really awful, because now you have the entirety of the `std` namespace, with lots and lots of commonly used names, colliding with the names you want to use in your code.